# Extending WP eCommerce Notification Emails in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, e-commerce

I am having a nightmare trying to extend the admin emails in wp ecommerce for wordpress.
The reports are very basic and no documentation to support adding to the emails.

I want to be able to add shipping address details to the admin report so I don't have to log into the Wordpress backend to view the purchase_log everytime I make a sale.

I have tried following an example from here http://getshopped.org/forums/topic/add-shipping-method-to-admin-email/ but with no luck.

I have added this:

```
    $report = str_replace( '%shipping_country%', $purchase_log['shipping_country'], $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%billing_country%', $purchase_log['billing_country'], $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%shipping_country%', $purchase_log['shipping_country'], $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%buyer_name%', wpsc_display_purchlog_buyers_name(), $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%shipping_address%', wpsc_display_purchlog_shipping_address(), $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%shipping_city%', wpsc_display_purchlog_shipping_city(), $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%shipping_country%', wpsc_display_purchlog_shipping_country(), $report );
```

to this (which is originally in wpsc_transaction_results_functions.php)

```
    $report = apply_filters( 'wpsc_transaction_result_report', $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%purchase_id%', $report_id, $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%product_list%', $report_product_list, $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%total_tax%', $total_tax, $report );
    $report = str_replace( '%total_shipping%', $total_shipping_email, $report );
```

etc...

but I get the following error after entering credit card details - does anyone know of a simple way to add to the report?
Cheers guys

[image: error after payment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know it's been a while since this was opened, but I found a solution to this. It's a bit messy, but it works.

So just above the filters in the above code within `wpsc-transaction_results_functions.php` above I created a database query that looked like this:

```
$cust_info = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM wp_wpsc_submited_form_data WHERE log_id = '$log_id'", ARRAY_A);
```

I then found out what parts of the array results was the information I needed, I did this by adding:

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($cust_info);
echo '</pre>';
```

I then put through an order and the array appeared on the transaction results screen. So I then set the variables...

```
$first_name = $cust_info[0]['value'];
$last_name = $cust_info[1]['value'];
$address_1 = $cust_info[2]['value'];
$city = $cust_info[3]['value'];
```

I then created the shortcodes i.e.

```
$message = str_replace( '%first_name%', $first_name, $message );
```

And don't forget to remove the `print_r ($cust_info);` etc.

Comment: Hero!! Thank you.

WP ecommerce replied to me and said this is something they will bring out in a future update. But this is great for now

Answer (score 1):

Found this post while looking for a similar problem...
I suggest using the shop styling plugin for wpsc.
http://haet.at/wp-ecommerce-shop-styling